# Submitting form using button on enter

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html form that I want to only submit from a button located outside my form.  I am using javascript to perform some verification and do not want the form to submit unless my javascript functions succeed.  I found that if I have the button inside the form it will always submit regardless of the javascript, but if I have it outside the form when a user presses enter it simply submits the form.  How can I force enter to perform the button javascript instead of submitting?

```
<form name="form1" action=<?$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'?'.$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]?> method="post">

<input type="text" maxlength="5" size="5" name="frmZip" value="">

<input type="hidden" name="frmLat" value="200">
<input type="hidden" name="frmLng" value="200">

<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" style="display:none" />
</form>
<button type="button" id="GetCoordinates" onclick="doClick();">Find Stores</button>
```

EDIT:
Found my solution.
I changed from

```
</form>
<button type="button" id="GetCoordinates" onclick="doClick();">Find Stores</button>
```

to

```
<input type="button" name="frmSubmit" onclick="doClick();" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This prevented the button from submitting the form so I submitted it in my doClick() via javascript.

EDIT 2:
While this seemed to work for a time, it has stopped catching the enter keystroke.  I updated my button to:

```
<input type="submit" name="frmSubmit" onclick="return doClick();" value="Find Stores">
```

And always returned false in doClick().  This allowed me to submit the form via javascript once everything had executed.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Your question legitimately makes no sense...

Comment: I was able to do it by changing the button to and input - type button, and calling my javascript from there.

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't answer your direct question, you can actually keep the button and simply use your validation on the form submit:

`<form onsubmit="return validateForm()">`

Then, in your `validateForm` method, return true or false indicating whether or not the validation has passed.

However to answer your direct question, you can also use the same approach on the submit button which will prevent the form from being submitted.

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments, an unontrusive solution is often desirable so here's that:

`document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = function() { return validateForm(); };`

Comment: I encourage you to assign javascript events *through* javascript using actual functions instead of functions-as-text in literal attributes (ala `obj.onsubmit = function() { ... };`). It is my understanding that professional web developers try to separate program code from markup.

Comment: @ErikE Valid comment and appreciated. Yes, unobtrusive JS is often the way to go.

Comment: Yes I agree with this answer. Keep the button regularly inside the form and use the return on submit event.

Comment: I've tried this but the form still submits regardless of the result of my javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your button inside the form will not submit the form on enter if you add preventDefault...

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {e.preventDefault();});
```

Comment: Not wrong, but is jQuery obligatory? What about `return false;`? A more complete answer would be nice.